# Unreachable code in Scala Pattern Matching

Tags: scala

Executing the below code

```
println("Pattern Matching by type")

val priceofCar : Any = 2.0
val priceType = priceofCar match{
    
    case price: Int => "Int"       // 1
    case price: Float => "Float"   // 2
    case price: Any => "Any"       // 3
    case price: Double => "Double" // 4
    case _ => "others"             // 5
}
// println(:type priceofCar)
println(s"Car price type = $priceType")
```

ends up with the below output

```
Car price type = Any
```

and a warning message

```
 warning: unreachable code
    case price: Double => "Double" // 4
                          ^
one warning found.
```

But, after swapping the order of rows //3 and //4, no warnings are shown and get the below output

```
Car price type = Double
```

Now my doubt is,

1. either it should stick to "Double" or "Any" in both cases, but not why ?
2. why the warning is thrown ?

Comment: Everything after the `case price: Any` is unreachable. It doesn't matter the type, `String`, `Boolean`, etc. because everything, no matter its type, is also type `Any`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
val priceType = priceofCar match{

    case price: Int => "Int"       // 1
    case price: Float => "Float"   // 2
    case price: Any => "Any"       // 3
    case price: Double => "Double" // 4
    case _ => "others"             // 5
}
```

The pattern matching is sequential for match which means it will first match price with 1st case which is price: Int then Float then Any and so on.

We should keep the most specific type first, As we can see in the diagram that Any is at the top of type hierachy (most generic type) it can consume anything that's the reason you are getting the warning useless code for lines after `case price: Any`

if you see in line 5 it says case price of type any which is on the top of hireachy of the types. It will match anything Int, Flot, String, List, or any user define data type.
that's why the lines below case price:Any are useless because the control is not going to the next case after Any.

[image]

Comment: I think it would be helpful to explain that _pattern matching_ works **Sequentially** - in other words, it goes one by one until one matches. That is why more specific cases must go first and more general ones must go at the end.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez yes you are right but I have heard a picture worth million words.

Comment: Well yes. However I don't think your image explains what I said - it clearly shows the Scala's _type_ hierarchy, which is great for understanding why `Any` will _sallow_ a `Double`. But it doesn't show that the match goes **Sequentially** - what I mean is that probably somebody having this problem may think that the `match` is able to automatically identify which is the correct branch, instead of knowing that it goes one by one until one matches. _(To be honest I had a similar doubt a couple of years ago when first learning Java with its `switch-case` statement)_.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez thanks for pointing out I will update the answer

Answer (score 3):

`case price: Any` match with anything including `Double` so if it before `case price: Double` later is newer matched.

Answer (score -2):

1. no, match case without break, if is match some condition and will return
2. match case require: more precise condition should be ahead

Comment: for 1, break is not required